# How to enable one vs one death messages in Counter Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

How to enable the death list in counter strike 1.6? I mean the notices we get on top right corner like this:

Steel >--------> Maverick
Panther >-------> Fanatic

I mean it shows which player killed which player, with which gun. In place of arrow I have shown, there's icon of gun.

These notices keep coming on game on top right corner. I accidentally enabled & disabled it but now I don't know how to bring it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hud_deathnotice_time** <time>

- 0 turns it off
- 1 or more displays that notice for <time> seconds

The default value is **6** seconds, so if you just want to revert it to default it's `hud_deathnotice_time 6`

Comment: Thanks. BTW it was enabled by default. I was playing Condition Zero game, in which Tutor is enabled by default. But when Tutor is enabled, these notices don't appear. So I pressed key I from keyboard and it solved all problems.